# Visual Studio 2013 & Windows 10 Pro - Blurry interface

Tags: visual-studio, interface, windows-10, intel

For a few months, my Visual Studio interface is getting blurry for no reason, I'm just coding, using auto completion and doing some alt-tab.
I'm using 100% DPI, and I tried to update all my graphics drivers but it didn't solve the problem.

Here are some screenshots that might help to understand what i'm facing.
[image: All blurry]

When i'm placing my arrow on it (like selection) it comes back clear, but not for long (about 5 min).
[image: After i selected text in editor]

Any idea of what to do to solve this ?

Comment: go into the VS options and turn off HW acceleration/UI effects

Comment: does turning HW acceleration off fix it or not?

Comment: My graphic card's driver wasn't up to date because windows forced me to use an old one because of my computer constructor recommandations. With the good graphic driver everything is working great.

Comment: ok, nice to hear this. Post your solution as answer and post which GPU you use and which driver fixes it, maybe other users run into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue in manually installing my graphic cards' last update driver, that windows was ignoring because of the constructor's limitation set on my computer, which is a HP Pro-Book 450 G2.

My computer has a Intel(R) HD Graphics Family for the display, and a AMD Radeon Graphics Processor for the render.

This both drivers were expired and were working good with the Windows 7 Pro I had, before upgrading my computer's OS for Windows 10 Pro.

The drivers i'm using now are :
- Intel(R) HD Graphics Family : v20.19.15.4501 (from 11 aug. 2016)
- AMD Radeon Graphics Processor : v21.17.413.0 (from 25 jan. 2017)

I hope it will help some people.